# scripted configuring of a linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

Given a list of kernel features, I want to create a minimal linux configuration supporting all given features (and the corresponding dependencies) but nothing else.

Is there a way to create a allnoconfig and a tool to enable features one by one?

(I could edit the `.config` file but this would not get dependencies right. I could use `make *config`, but as far as I know those work only interactive or create some default config.)

Comment: Here is a script that automates Linux kernel configuration with dependency resolution: [Kernel Expect (kernelexpect)](https://github.com/perkint/kernelexpect)

Answer (score 1):

Since kernel 2.6.29 there is a script that you can find in 
`/kernel_extracted_dir/scripts/config`

For example

```
/kernel_extracted_dir/scripts/config --set-val CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT 14
/kernel_extracted_dir/scripts/config --enable CONFIG_PRINTK_TIME
```

(To give credit where it is due, I took the example from this [blog](http://www.embedded-bits.co.uk/2013/script-kconfig-options/))

You have the follwing options (copied from the help)

```
--enable|-e option   Enable option
--disable|-d option  Disable option
--module|-m option   Turn option into a module
--set-str option string
                     Set option to "string"
--set-val option value
                     Set option to value
--undefine|-u option Undefine option
--state|-s option    Print state of option (n,y,m,undef)

--enable-after|-E beforeopt option
                         Enable option directly after other option
--disable-after|-D beforeopt option
                         Disable option directly after other option
--module-after|-M beforeopt option
                         Turn option into module directly after other option commands can be repeated multiple times

options:
    --file config-file   .config file to change (default .config)
    --keep-case|-k       Keep next symbols' case (dont' upper-case it)
```

Comment: This seem great at the first look. Unfortunately it seems not to care about dependencies at all. :(

Comment: @michas, use `make oldconfig` after configuring the `.config` file with `scripts/config`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it non-interactively, you might be able to use make oldconfig or make olddefconfig. make *config will fix the dependencies and those aren't as verbose as, say menuconfig. (Otherwise menuconfig is perfectly fine for enabling features one by one, it even includes the help texts!)

make oldconfig will ask for any 'new' configuration options, so you would need to insert comments like this for any disabled options if you want to work non-interactively:

```
# CONFIG_KERNEL_GZIP is not set
```

make olddefconfig on the other hand doesn't seem to ask, but uses a default value. There's also silentoldconfig, but it also asks in some cases, so it's not that silent.

from make help:

```
oldconfig       - Update current config utilising a provided .config as base
silentoldconfig - Same as oldconfig, but quietly, additionally update deps
olddefconfig    - Same as silentoldconfig but sets new symbols to their default value
```

Disclaimer: I only tried the trivial test of removing the options for some libraries I know were needed. They were added back by olddefconfig and oldconfig. I don't know how this applies to doing a larger configuration.

In any case, I suppose you already considered using make localmodconfig or something like that before starting this? I haven't tried making a minimal config in years, but I seem to remember there were some rather non-obvious ways to create totally unusable kernels. :)

Comment: "olddefconfig" would probably work fine, too. Is there a way to get the default config options from a defconfig file? (In that case the defconfig file would give a suitable base and minimal custom option could be set in .config.)